# How to make underline tabs position in center?

Tags: react-native, native-base

i want to customize the tabs underline on center.
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eJyK.png)
i already use alignItem, justifyContent and its not working. thanks

*here is my code

```
<Footer>
<Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#00CBFF', width: 100}}>
<Tab1>
<Tab2>
</Tabs>
</Footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the following property to your parent view.

```
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
```

It will set your layout with the same space for both tab and it will set in the center.

Answer (score 0):

If the underline is what the style is being applied to, you would need to use `alignSelf`.

`alignItem` and `justifyContent` effects all children components, not the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use marginHorizontal like this:

```
<Tabs
      tabContainerStyle={styles.topTabBG}
      tabBarBackgroundColor="#f0f0f0"
      tabBarUnderlineStyle={{
        width: 50,
        height: 3,
        marginHorizontal: Dimensions.get('window').width / 9.5,
        backgroundColor: '#5e7584',
      }}>
```